# Word "augmentation"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

**I'm interested to know if the word *"augmentation"* has a meaning of *"an additional piece that adds-up to something"*.**

As an example, suppose we look at Iron Man (Marvel). he had this power source in the middle of his chest. *Could it be an "augmentation", "extension", "addition", or maybe a "supplement"?*

*I was surprised to see Wikipedia use "augmented" when speaking of adding weapons and different tools to Tony Stark's suit.*

Quote: [Later, Stark augments his suit with weapons and other technological devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man)

[As Oxford says](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/augment):

```
:to make (something) greater by adding to it; increase.
```

[As Merriam-Webster says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment):

```
:to make greater, more numerous, larger, or more intense.
:supplement She took a second job to augment her income.
```

[As Cambridge says](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/augment):

```
:to increase the size or value of something by adding something to it.
```

Comment: I don't think its very clear what you are asking. Could you change your post so that the question is clearly marked?

Comment: Your example (about the Arc Reactor on Stark's chest) and the quote are quite different. If I remember correctly, his Arc Reactor was used to save his life (he would die soon without it), so I don't think *augment* is the right word for it.